# Unable to load static front page on home url

Tags: urls, migration, frontpage, home-url

I installed wordpress in `/wp/` directory. So in my blog every URL had `/wp/` in it. I followed multiple articles(1,2) and was able to remove the 'wp' from URLs.

before - `example.com/wp/post-1-name`
after - `example.com/post-1-name`

In permalink settings I have selected -

post name - `http://example.com/sample-post/`

Now every url I open do not have `/wp/` in it. **Except** front page.

In 'reading settings' I also set the 'front page display' to 'a static page' and selected lets say 'Introduction' as the front page.

When I open urls in browser all urls except home page (example.com) works fine but when I open homepage or click on the page url of "introduction" page (which is static front page), a message is shown -

> This Website is Under Construction.
>   Come Back Soon.

[image]

Going to `http://example.com/wp/` shows 'not found' page.

[image]

In my general settings -
WordPress Address (URL) -> http://example.com/wp
Site Address (URL) -> http://uptuplacements.com

Index.php file content in **root** `public_html` directory.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Content of index.php file in `public_html/wp/` directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

content of .htaccess file in **root** `public_html` directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

content of .htaccess file in `public_html/wp/` directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any suggestions how can I load the front page on home url?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEnKI.png) https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njQSZ.png) http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-get-rid-of-wordpress-from-your-wordpress-site-url/

Comment: The "under construction" banner is loaded somehow by  http://uptuplacements.com/index.php. Are you sure you followed the instructions by wp-beginner to upload a modified index.php file to the root directory of your wordpress site (not to /wp/)?

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions by wp-beginner. updating the question.

Comment: I think "under construction" is loaded from your root index.php file try to find your root index.php file and update index.php with upper code that you mention. also have a look [http://askwpgirl.com/move-wordpress-from-subdirectory-to-root-directory/

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved the issue.
 `Index.html` file in `/public_html/` directory was conflicting with `index.php` file.

This awesome article solved the issue.
[askwpgirl.com/moving-wordpress-from-subdirectory-to-root-faq/](http://askwpgirl.com/moving-wordpress-from-subdirectory-to-root-faq/)